# Is there a way to check if NoiseSuppressor was applied?

Tags: android, record, noise, noise-reduction

I made an app that can record audio using NoiseSuppressor with Flutter. I changed the native android java code. I recorded with my tablet and listened both NS version recording and original's but I can't see the difference...How can i tell if it is applied? Is there a way to, like log, print or something?

Comment: Of course, NoiseSuppressor.isAvailable() is true in my test case.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyse your recordings via software like a Audacity. For example in Audacity you are able to generate spectrogram view. If there are meaningful differences between two audio files, you will be able to see differences in the spectrogram.

[Audacity spectrogram manual](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/spectrogram_view.html)

[Audacity page](https://www.audacityteam.org/)

Comment: Thank for the answer. I already checked the spectrogram but I cannot see meaningful differences..in that case do you think NS was not applied?